# Json api decoding

Tags: php, html, json, decode

here is my json

```
{
  "rgInventory": {
           "5455029633": {
                           "id":"5455029633",
                           "classid":"310776543",
                           "instanceid":"302028390",
                           "amount":"1"
            }
  }
}
```

Here is my way to parse json in php

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198201055225/inventory/json/730/2");
$decode = json_decode($content);
foreach($decode->rgInventory->5455029633  as $appid){
    echo $appid->id;
}
```

I need to get that 5455029633 but it dont work in foreach.
And I want to store it in the variable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json, which you've provided is invalid. Remove last comma from `"amount":"1",` and you are missing closing curly bracket. Then you should be able to access desired value as `$decode->rgInventory->{"5455029633"}`.

Or make your life simpler ;) and just go for assoc array `$decode = json_decode($content, true);`

Comment: What if I have hundreds of "5455029633" that are all different and i need to echo all or get it into variable?

Comment: As I wrote, you can go for assoc array instead of object, and then everything is trivial. Or you can stay with stdclass and iterate through its properties as shown here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php - standard loop works well: `php > foreach ($decode->rgInventory as $key => $v) {var_dump($key);}
string(10) "5455029633"`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass true as second argument to the function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get an array instead of an object :

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198201055225/inventory/json/730/2");
  $decode = json_decode($content, true);
  echo $decode['rgInventory']['6255037137']['id']; // will output the property 'id' of the inventory 6255037137
  $invetory = $decode['rgInventory']['6255037137'] // will store the inventory 6255037137 in the variable $inventory

?>
```